# Expectation of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, summation

In the proof of the expectation of the binomial distribution,

$$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}=p\frac{d}{dp}(p+q)^n=pn(p+q)^{n-1}=np$$

Why is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}= p\frac{d}{dp}(p+q)^n$?

I know that by the binomial theorem $(p+q)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the sum over $k$ in the binomial theorem. If you add it and perform the differentiation and multiplication termwise, you'll get the desired result.

Comment: I edited it.Thanks.

Comment: @ronjacobs: Should I take that to mean that your question is still open after this correction? If so, I think you'll have to state more specifically which part you're having trouble with. Did you try to differentiate and multiply termwise? If so, where did you encounter a problem?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\sum_{k=0}^n k\tbinom nkp^kq^{n-k}
\\[1ex]&=\sum_{k=0}^n\tbinom nk p(kp^{k-1})q^{n-k}
\\[1ex]&=\sum_{k=0}^n\tbinom nkp(\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial p}p^k)q^{n-k}
\\[1ex]&=p\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial p}\sum_{k=0}^n\tbinom nkp^kq^{n-k}
\\[1ex]&=p\tfrac {\partial~~}{\partial p}(p+q)^n
\\[1ex]&=np(p+q)^{n-1}
\\[1ex]&=np\end{align}$$